# Does YouTube use FTP to upload?

Tags: http, upload, ftp, youtube

sorry maybe a dumb question...

I'm curious if YouTube (for example) uses FTP to upload videos?  I was trying to look around the source of the upload page and saw it seemed like they do some kind of plugin detection for Java, Flash, Silverlight, etc... does this mean they use one of those to have the client make an FTP connection and do an upload instead of doing a normal HTML form, HTTP upload?

Thanks for any enlightenment =)

Answer (score 3):

No, they use HTTP for file uploads. FTP is considered non-secure protocol over the internet.

Comment: To be fair, a non-HTTPS HTTP upload would be just as insecure in terms of the data payload.

Answer (score 1):

If ever you want to know what is happening between your computer and another one, I highly recommend downloading Wireshark ( http://www.wireshark.org/ ).  This will show you exactly what is going on between the browser, any plugins and youtube.com.